# UIPinchGestureRecognizer questions with subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following code:

```
m_singleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, nWidth - 1, nHeight - 1)];
m_singleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinch:)];
[pinchGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[m_singleView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
[m_singleView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[m_MainView addSubview:m_singleView];
```

The issue that I'm having is that the pinch event for some reason does not fire. However, if i change line from `[m_singleView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture]` to `[m_MainView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];` then everything will work fine... can I not add the event for subview only?

Thanks!

Comment: Adding the gesture recognizer to the subview should not be a problem. You should give the subview a regular color to check if it is large enough and that you really tap on that subview.

Comment: As Andre mentioned, it should work fine with subviews. What are nWidth, and nHeight values?

Comment: its 320 and 240, so def not a size issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,you can add gesture to subview. i tested your code like below works fine.

First add delegate.

`@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`

```html
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   
   UIView *m_singleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, self.view.frame.size.width - 50, self.view.frame.size.height - 50)];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    m_singleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinch)];
    pinchGesture.delegate=self;
    [pinchGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
    [m_singleView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
    [m_singleView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:m_singleView];
}

-(void)pinch{
    NSLog(@"In PInch");
}
```

you have used pinchgesture so you can use it like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Debug view hierarchy to see whether the size of m_singleView are 0 or not? If so, the size of m_singleView needs to be changed until you can touch it.